# Access path for crossdomain.xml file for jwplayer

Tags: asp.net, cross-domain, flash, jwplayer, azure-blob-storage

I am using JWPlayer to stream videos from Azure blob storage, JWPlayer needs `crossdomain.xml` to play the video.

I tried to place `crossdomain.xml` file in the root directory and the code in `http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1/crossdomain.xml` but JWPlayer looks for it in `http://127.0.0.1:10000/crossdomain.xml`.

Is there anyway to redirect JWPlayer to `http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1/crossdomain.xml` rather than the default `http://127.0.0.1:10000/crossdomain.xml`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I often use this code snippet to Create Crossdomainpolicy:

```
var account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[ConfigKey]);
            var blobs = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            CreateCrossDomainPolicy(blobs);

 private static void CreateCrossDomainPolicy(CloudBlobClient blobs)
    {
        try
        {
            blobs.GetContainerReference("$root").CreateIfNotExist();
            blobs.GetContainerReference("$root").SetPermissions(
                new BlobContainerPermissions()
                {
                    PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob
                });
            var blob = blobs.GetBlobReference("clientaccesspolicy.xml");
            blob.Properties.ContentType = "text/xml";
            blob.UploadText(@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
                <access-policy>
                  <cross-domain-access>
                    <policy>
                      <allow-from http-methods=""*"" http-request-headers=""*"">
                        <domain uri=""*"" />
                        <domain uri=""http://*"" />
                      </allow-from>
                      <grant-to>
                        <resource path=""/"" include-subpaths=""true"" />
                      </grant-to>
                    </policy>
                  </cross-domain-access>
                </access-policy>");
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            throw Ex;
        }
    }
```

In the ConfigKey i will pass my Actual Azure storage account key or Uselocalstorage=true

Answer (score -1):

You could try to configure the webserver to fetch from wherever in the document root, which I assume is in `/devstoreaccount/`, the file is located and return it when `/crossdomain.xml` is requested.

Or, you could symlink `/devstoreaccount/crossdomain.xml` **-->** `/crossdomain.xml`. And this wouldn't break your code if somehow it was linked to `/devstoreaccount/crossdomain.xml.`